# Intro to non-threaded async IO for C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, io

I work on a desktop app team composed of "UI developers" (us) and "C++ developers" (them). The C++ devs are responsible for getting us all the data that we display in the UI, so they do all the IO, database access, web calls, etc.

Recently we've run into some serious performance problems with IO blocking the UI thread. Of course, the solution to this is to make the IO asynchronous. But the C++ devs insist this is only possible by spawning a new thread, which is as we know very expensive.

I know from Node.js etc. that async IO doesn't need to involve threads. I know that Win32, and presumably Macs, do have an event loop. But, I have no idea what solutions are prevalent in C++ land for doing async non-threaded IO. (Maybe that libuv thing that underlies node?).

Can anyone point to some popular libraries, or better yet tutorial articles, so we can introduce this concept to our C++ devs? Bonus points for cross-platform (PC and Mac). More bonus points if there is an async non-threaded database solution, since I believe our use of SQLite is the source of many of our problems.

Comment: "_spawning a new thread, which is as we know very expensive_".  I see this opinion a lot.  And I have to say, I don't know it to be "very expensive".  It is highly dependent upon your specific use case, and the cases where additional threads "should be avoided" is much smaller than the general case that should embrace them.

Comment: Our app requires reading the properties of every file in a user's ebook library, which in some cases can be upward of 1500 files. 1500 threads is not acceptable.

Comment: However, you could do that in one thread.  1500 items is an incredibly small work queue.

Comment: Yes, one background thread and one UI thread is quite acceptable. But the C++ devs tell us each async operation requires its own thread. I know that's not true if you use async non-threaded IO in the background thread, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @Domenic: Which platform are you working on ?

Comment: Your "C++ devs" are lying to you.  :p  I cannot generalize and say that really, but I don't see why you would require one thread per IO.  Sounds like they've designed themselves into a corner.

Comment: @Chad Not designed, C-plus-plused (remember, we're talking UI guys vs C++ guys) :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Boost Asynchronous I/O (asio)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html). They have an [excellent tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) and several [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html). It is cross platform.

Comment: It doesn't have to.  You can use WM_TIMER messages and run the async task scheduler using `boost::asio::io_service::poll_one()`.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html                this page says that it is indeed not creating any threads on its own but I guess that you would need at least 1 thread as the `Proactor` to call `io_service::run()` in order to process the finished read/writes. edit: or you do what @Chad said :P

Comment: Sweet, convinced. +1; will leave as unaccepted for a bit to try to attract more answers, but you're on track to get the green checkmark :).

Comment: unless you fancy implementing your own based on completion ports - I would already accept this answer... :)

Comment: @Nim: I mean, that's what libuv did, and I was hoping someone would post a libuv tutorial link.

Comment: AFAIK,Boost asio is basically for dealing with sockets. I dont think it can be done for file reading,database access.

Comment: @ArunMu Boost.Asio is designed around sockets, but the proactor can be used for any asynchronous jobs you want.  It does not have to be networking code.  I've used it as a general purpose Async task provider for many projects.

Comment: @Chad: Hmm.. thats news for me. Thanks for the info. Have you even used it for file handling ?

Comment: @ArunMu You can do anything you want in your completion handlers, just `post` your "job" objects to the `io_service`.  Now, that's not to say it will magically not block for you (functions can still block, and if you have only one thread that can be an issue).  Using wrapped jobs (as execution handlers) in conjunction with `deadline_timer` objects can be very flexible.