# Really confused about C++ multithreading

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gtk

I'm trying to write some multi-threaded code in C++, but I can't seem to get anywhere. I've done some research, but I struggle to find some basic examples that would show me how to achieve what I need. I'm working on a Gtk application in Linux and every time there is a time consuming operation, like loading a file, the GUI locks (and if I try to move it all controls etc. disappear just leaving blank windows). This can obviously be solved by threading, but I'm not sure where to even start looking. Should I use pthreads, C++ Thread, boost::Thread, Glib::Thread? What are the differences and reasons to use any of the above?

My aim is to have a message dialog or even a progress bar dialog which would show when there is an operation running in the background. Basically anything that would leave the GUI responsive while the stuff is being done. I'd really appreciate some example or a link to some source code to study.

Comment: You should be looking into the idle handler, and breaking down the process into smaller chunks.

Comment: Even though it can "obviously" be solved by threads, it doesn't mean it is the right way.

Comment: I don't know much about Gtk but I doubt that it would be clever to add another (huge) library like Boost to your application. You could start off by using `pthread` which invokes a certain function in your application handler as soon as the thread is finished.

Comment: You typically don't want to do operations like waiting for IO by simply doing the blocking operation on a background thread. Doing this leaves a thread sitting idle while it waits, using up resources when you would be better off doing asynchronous IO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522475/intro-to-non-threaded-async-io-for-c

Comment: @bames53 what resources? Why would it leave a thread sitting idle? (Async I/O is generally a better solution to this problem, sure, but I can't make sense of what you claim to be downsides to multithreading)

Comment: @jalf it uses up a thread and associated memory and kernel resources. It sits idle because the operation is IO bound and not CPU bound, so the thread doesn't actually have any work to do while waiting on the IO.

Comment: What does it even mean to "use up a thread"? It's not like there's a fixed number of threads available. Yes, it uses a small amount of memory... which, because it isn't actively accessed, can be paged out if you're low on memory. And the thread will, assuming you write sane code, be suspended as long as there's no work, blocked on some kind of synchronization primitive. All in all, the cost would be effectively zero.

Comment: @jalf In fact there is a maximum number of threads available. Also I think idle threads waiting on IO will be periodically woken up. And the kernel still has to keep track of them.

Comment: No there is not. Not if you are running a sane real-world OS. Of course there are practical limits, because each thread requires a bit of memory (some of which is in the kernel which generally has fixed-sized buffers), and sooner or later you'll run out, but there is no fixed limit on how many threads you can have. And no, again assuming a *competent* implementation, an idle thread will be suspended until the event it is blocked on is fired. And as long as it is suspended, there is nothing to "keep track of". It does not enter the scheduler or require any actual processing while blocked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9920/discussion-between-jalf-and-bames53)

Comment: The problem is, I suspect, FUD from the .NET camp.  Managed threads are, aparrently, so expensive that M$-slave developers will go to almost any lengths to avoid using a dedicated thread for anything.  If it cannot be done asynchronously on a threadpool, they won't do it :)

Comment: .. and lack of knowledge of preemptive multithreading operation.  Like some have posted, a thread that is not ready is just an object pointer on a queue to some driver or synchro object.  The scheduler/dispatcher is only interested in the ready threads on its priority queues.  It never sees the other 1000 threads that are not ready/running.  Idle threads waiting on IO are not woken up unless some IO is signaled by the driver it is waiting on, (or perhaps it has reached the front of the delta-queue that the OS uses to manage timeouts).

Comment: The chat has apparently disappeared, so I'll re-ask my question here. You say "Async I/O is generally a better solution to this problem". Perhaps you'd care to explain why that is if the cost of threads is "effectively zero." Also I didn't claim that there was a fixed limit on threads. I said there was a maximum number, which you acknowledge to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use GTK there are a few things you need to take into account. GTK is thread aware but not thread safe. It provides a global lock controlled by gdk_threads_enter()  and gdk_threads_leave() which protects all use of GTK+. That is, only one thread can use GTK+ at any given time. Callbacks require a bit of attention. Callbacks from GTK+ (signals) are made within the GTK+ lock. However callbacks from GLib (timeouts, IO callbacks, and idle functions) are made outside of the GTK+ lock. So, within a signal handler you do not need to call gdk_threads_enter(), but within the other types of callbacks, you do.

Read this for more information:

http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GTK+ProgrammingTips.html

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-faq/stable/x481.html

The kind of threads you probably need is a normal worker thread. It leaves the gui responsive while the work is done in the background. The gui then can control the worker thread and also check the worker threads progress with a timerbased check on what its doing and updates to a progress bar or showing a message dialog.

Look at some tutorials for general multi-threading in c++ on linux here:

http://www.tidytutorials.com/2010/06/linux-c-socket-example-with-client.html

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

http://programming-in-linux.blogspot.jp/2008/03/multithreading-example-in-cc-using.html

Answer (score 5):

There is now a standard thread library, so you should use that if your compiler supports it.

If you're stuck with an old compiler, then Boost.Thread is the best choice, since it is very similar to the standard library, and so the conversion will be straightforward when you update your compiler.

However, you may well be better off sticking to one thread, and using asynchronous I/O to avoid blocking.

Comment: Can you link me to documentation for std::thread? I cannot find any reference to such a thing's existence.

Comment: There's some readable information on std::thread at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2184.html. Alternatively, there's now a pretty good book on threading in the new C++ standard here:

http://www.manning.com/williams/

Comment: @Griwes What a great link! But how do you get the new C++ standard?

Comment: @Aerovistae: The cheapest place I found to buy the final standard is [ANSI](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC+14882-2012); or you can download the free public draft from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf). The draft is very similar to the final standard, but there are probably a few differences.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the environment you're working in.

If possible, use the standard library threading functionality. It requires a recent compiler (actually I'm not sure if GCC has implemented it *at all* yet), but *if* it is available, use it.

It's a very nice API, and it's standard and portable.

I'd consider POSIX a kind of last resort. It's the lowest-level common denominator on *nix systems, but it's not a nice API to work with. All the others you mention are basically wrappers around this. On the other hand, you avoid third-party dependencies.

I haven't used Glib::Thread, but my experience with Glib is that it's... kind of icky.

If standard library threads are not available, my preferred library would be Boost's. It's a very similar API to `std::thread` (the latter was modelled after Boost.Thread), and it works really well.

The downside, of course, is that it means depending on a third-party library.

Comment: Can you link me to documentation for std::thread? I cannot find any reference to such a thing's existence.

Comment: What are you looking for? Proof of its existence can be found by looking in the standard (otherwise, check [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Threading_facilities). If you want docs on how to use it, google turns up [this](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/thread/thread.html) reference, for example. It has been implemented in Microsoft's VC11 beta too. I'm not sure about GCC and Clang. I'm pretty sure I've seen at least one platform where one of them had an implementation, but can't remember which. :)

Comment: That second link claims to be "the only vendor selling a complete implementation of the C++0x standard thread library." Wtf? Since when do you purchase C++?

Comment: @Aerovistae he's not selling C++, he's selling an implementation of the C++0x standard thread library. ;) In other words, if you either (a) need to write threading code, and would prefer to use the standard library API, but your compiler of choice doesn't yet implement it, you can buy an implementation of the library. And (b) if you're selling a compiler, you might license parts of the library from third parties. For example, Microsoft licenses their STL implementation from DinkumWare. Just two ways in which it might make sense to sell a (part of a) standard library implementation

Answer (score 2):

Threading in c++ is platform dependent prior to C++11 (e.g pthreads vs windows threads) since interaction with the kernel is usually required.  boost:Thread is the platform independent way to do it (it does the platform dependent stuff under the hood) or C++11 , if you have access to it, supports threading as well (based on boost::thread).

If you dont care about any platform other than the one you are working on then I have used pthreads on linux and regular win32 threads on windows both of which were pretty simple to get up and running with.

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with Gtk, however looking at [GTK+ Programming tips](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GTK+ProgrammingTips.html), it seems that [GDK Threads](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDK_Threads.html) is the most suitable option.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn (with a lot of example code to run) for both win32 API and UNIX.

[WIN32 And UNIX Thread & Semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms811896.aspx)